# Response Writefile isn't creating a PDF when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, response.write, writefile

I'm using the following code to send a PDF to users to open/download.  This works fine in IE9.  Any ideas why it won't work in Chrome?

```
Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= \"" + myFile + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myFile.Length.ToString());

Response.WriteFile(myFile.FullName);

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

Comment: That's not working.  I had also tried Response.ContentType="application/octet-stream", but that didn't work either.

Comment: It turns out I had bigger problems, and my Response code wasn't even being reached in Chrome.  Once I straightened that out, the PDF loaded just fine, without the need to specify the ContentType... but I realize it's best practice to list the ContentType.  Thanks